# Trouble creating a URL. Unable to reach the Branch servers, please try again shortly

Tags: android, titanium, hybrid-mobile-app, branch.io

I am using Branch IO Android SDK, but since yesterday I've been receiving an error:

> Trouble creating a URL. Unable to reach the Branch servers, please try again shortly.

I've verified my code again but this is still occurring. I can't find any solutions to this.

Comment: The Branch service is up and running. You can check the status [here](status.branch.io). Could you write into integrations@branch.io so that the team can help you with your issue?